# How Display 3 Posts in one Loop ??? Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
  <?php $i=1; ?>
                  <?php $dayes = DB::table('days')->where('Doc',$item->id)->get(); ?> 
                                    @foreach($dayes as $DAY)
                <?php $timess = DB::table('times')->where('days_id',$DAY->id)->get(); ?>

                     @foreach($timess as $timer)  
                 <div class="table-times"> </div>
  <?php $i++; ?>
                            </div>
                         @endforeach 
                         @endforeach
```

i need to display class table-times  3 in one loop

Comment: Maybe if you format your code properly, it'll be a bit easier to see what's going on. That code hurts my brain.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, 3 in one iteration:

```
@foreach($timess as $timer)  
    <div class="table-times"> </div>
    <div class="table-times"> </div>
    <div class="table-times"> </div>
```

Comment: inside this div am display data from database  i need it automatically when display three div of class table-times  go to next active :  
same sliders

     <div class="carousel-item  <?php   if($i == 1) { ?>   active  <?php  } ?>  ">